# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in hjs-webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack

Following tutorial from [Fullstack.io: create yelp clone](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-yelp-clone)

In my webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path'),


join = path.join,
resolve = path.resolve;


const root = resolve(__dirname);
const src = join(root, 'src');
const modules = join(root, 'node_modules');
const dest = join(root, 'dist');

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const isDev = NODE_ENV === 'development';

const getConfig = require('hjs-webpack');
var config = getConfig({
    isDev: isDev,
    in: join(src, 'app.js'),// entry point file
    out: dest,
    // blow away any previously built files before it starts building new ones
    clearBeforeBuild: true
    });


config.module.loaders.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: [modules],
    loader: 'style!css'
  })


module.exports = config;
```

when running the dev. serve i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\projects\React\yelpReact\webpack.config.js:90:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\projects\React\yelpReact\node_modules\hjs-webpack\bin\hjs-dev-server.js:17:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
Failed to load webpack config, please use like this
hjs-dev-server.js webpack.config.js
```

turns out the **config.module.loaders is returning null**, what exactly am i doing wrong here, i never used used "hjs-webpack", appreciate any help

Comment: Check `config.module` before you try to access `.loaders` to push something into it.  Looks like just a config issue.

Comment: I did that as mentioned in my comment below the code, console.log on (config.module.loaders) and it always returns undefined, the only property that returns an array of objects is (config.module.rules)

Answer (score 1):

`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` suggests that `config.module.loaders` is undefined.

It is a webpack config, and in webpack configs, the loaders are in `module.rules` and `module.loaders` is not recognized I think (and 
 therefore probably not returned by `getConfig`).

I suggest that you try and replace `modules` by `rules` like so:

```
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: [modules],
        loader: 'style!css'
    });
```

[Resource on webpack configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Comment: That works, thanks. Problem is the tutorial is last updated 3 years ago i'm getting errors in other parts

Comment: hjs-webpack doesn't do much, by keeping an eye on the webpack configuration you should be able to go through the tutorial. Or discard hjs-webpack altogether since it's pretty easy to configure webpack 4 from scratch and you will find many info on the subject in the community

Answer (score 0):

WP loaders reside in the `rules` subarray.

Also - a quick inspection of the export in `hjs-webpack` shows that indeed there's no `loaders` property on the `module` object.

Thus - you should update your code as follows:

```
config.module.loaders.push({
test: /\.css$/,
include: [modules],
loader: 'style!css'})
```

[hjs-webpack/blob/master/index.js#L158](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/hjs-webpack/blob/master/index.js#L158)

[WP Config specs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)